# My Wallet address / password

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, linux

I'm mining to my address and I can see the accumulation of my ether when I go to my mining pool's website but I'm still unsure of how the wallet works. I don't remember if I got my wallet address through https://www.myetherwallet.com/#generate-wallet or through geth on my Linux terminal or through the Ethereum Wallet GUI on my Linux desktop. When I check my address at https://eth.nanopool.org/account/0xADDRESS I click the 'View with address only' bubble but it doesn't ask for a password. It shows that I have 0.00 ETH but I think that's just because I haven't mined enough for a payout on my pool's website yet. How does the wallet work, where is the password stored. If I create a wallet address on geth through my command line how would a site like MyEtherWallt even be able to verify that the password is correct? And vise versa. If I create a wallet at the MyEtherWall website how would either my geth terminal or my GUI Ether Wallet be able to verify or authenticate my password. Thanks.